How to use nginx and RTMP in Github codespaces?
I've made a livestreaming server with nginx and RTMP and it works fine in localhost. But it does not work in Github codespaces, any fixes?
This is the code used from the repo
I was expecting my stream to work through OBS, the webpage loads as expected. But the stream does not work.
